# como desabilitar rotacion a mi aplicacion? REACT-NATIVE

Tags: javascript, android-studio, react-native

Quiero desabilitar la rotacion a mi app, he buscado y al parecer tengo que agregar en
`AndroidManifest.xml:` esta linea: `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`, pero una vez que la agrego no me deja correr el emulador, dandome este error:

`C:\Users\****\App\android\app\build\generated\not_namespaced_r_class_sources\debug\r\androidx\arch`

[image]

abri la app con expo, pero aun puedo rotar la app, por lo que veo no se si funcionara o funcione

Answer (score 1):

Si está creando sus aplicaciones React Native con Expo, puede usar el `orientation`campo en su app.json archivo, por ejemplo:

```
{
 "expo": {
 "name": "My app",
 "slug": "my-app",
 "sdkVersion": "21.0.0",
 "privacy": "public",
 "orientation": "portrait"
 }
}
```

Se puede configurar en "portrait", "landscape"o lo "default"que significa rotar automáticamente sin bloqueo de orientación.

agreguelo y vuelva a ejecutar el app, mas informacion en:

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/screen-orientation/#screenorientationorientation

Comment: ok, y en el caso del android studio?

Comment: pues es tal cual lo planteas en la pregunta,pon en la pregunta el screen del AndroidManifest.xml  mejor y asi vemos si esta bien